# How to delete a element by tag name with all elements inside it

Tags: php, xml, removeclass

I want to use the dom removeChild function in php to remove everything between a tag.

my xml looks like

```
<root>
  <element>text</element>

  <remove>
    text
    <morexml>text</morexml>
  </remove>
</root>
```

Now I want to remove the  tag including its entire inside. How do I do this? I do not have a clue. I am trying to use the only dom function i found: removeChild.

When removed it has to look like this:

```
 <root>
      <element>text</element>

 </root>
```

Is there a php dom function to do this? I can not find it on google or stackoverflow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153697/php-delete-xml-element

Comment: You can try to do it with regex. following link might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226562/how-can-i-remove-an-entire-html-tag-and-its-contents-by-its-class-using-a-rege

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$dom->getElementsByTagName('root')->item(0)
   ->removeChild($dom->getElementsByTagName('remove')->item(0));
```

This is very specific, though.  You can use XPath if you need more generality:

```
foreach ($xpath->query('//remove') as $node) {
   $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath and delete over XPath the node.

[Use DOM and XPath to remove a node from a sitemap file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752942/use-dom-and-xpath-to-remove-a-node-from-a-sitemap-file)

[PHP SimpleXML - Remove xpath node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442314/php-simplexml-remove-xpath-node)

here on Stackoverflow are a lot of posts. Perhaps you should search here at first.