# How can I remove these tags and its contents?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have these `<sub>` tags in HTML.  I need to remove them and their contents.

So far I have this, but it removes just the tags and not the contents.

```
$string = preg_replace("#</?sub[^>]*>#is", "", $string);
```

Can someone please help me finish this?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226562/how-can-i-remove-an-entire-html-tag-and-its-contents-by-its-class-using-a-rege

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_replace("#<sub.*?>.*?</sub>#", "", $string);
```

This is not very dependable, and depending on the circumstances you probably want to use a real html/xml parser.  PHP has two great ones that are built in: DOMDocument and SimpleXML.

Comment: I'd throw in an `i` flag for case insensitivity and `s` for multiline just for good measure.