# Replace all text, including newlines, between two strings with perl

Tags: regex, perl, replace, newline

I have several hundred readme files which follow a specific format. I need to replace a chunk of text in each one with different content. Everything is working great except I'm unable to select the words if there are newlines `\n` between the words. An example is as follows:

```
...
this
is

old


content
...
```

I would like to replace all the text in these files so they look like this

```
...
new content
...
```

I have tried the following perl commands but they do not work with the newlines

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/this(\n|.)*?content/new content/g;' *.txt
```

I have tried adding the /s tag based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/226601/4975772 (perhaps I'm doing this incorrectly..)

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/this(\n|.)*?content/new content/gs;' *.txt
```

Without the "?"

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/this(\n|.)*content/new content/g;' *.txt
```

Using (.+?) instead of (\n|.) based on [Regex to match any character including new lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8303488/4975772)

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/this(.+?)*content/new content/g;' *.txt
```

Using [\s\S] instead of (\n|.) based on [Regex to match any character including new lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303488/regex-to-match-any-character-including-new-lines)

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/this[\s\S]*content/new content/g;' *.txt
```

I have tried these expressions inside regexpal.com and they reportedly work perfectly.

[image: regexpal example]

If I remove the newlines from the readme files, everything works perfectly for **all** of these example perl commands. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the file is read line by line and not at once..so it is happening

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to add the `0777`. So your one liner should be.

```
perl -0777 -pi -e 's/this.*?content/new content/sg;' *.txt
```

`0777` is a slurp mode. It pass entire files to your script in `$_`

This is equal to `local $/;`

```
 open my $fh,"<","file";
 local $/;
 my $s = <$fh>;
```

Here the whole file will store into the `$s`.

Then, no need to add the `\n` in your pattern. Because `s` modifier to allow the `.` to match the any character including newlines.